# My SQSListener returns body as messageID, And How do I get send MessageId with QueueMessagingTemplate Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-messaging, spring-cloud-aws

I have 2 issues regarding Spring AWS-SQS sdk, (Or maybe I am doing it wrong).

First is that I used CLI earlier and I managed to get the message Id of the sent message example:

```
aws sqs send-message --queue-url https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/testqueue --message-body hooray   

'{
    "MD5OfMessageBody": "d3101ad", 
    "MessageId": "jdhj-933"
}
```

Now I tried with `spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging` and I setup a Queue Messaging template like this

```
private final QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;

  public SqsQueueService(@Qualifier("amazonSQSAsync") final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQS) {
    this.queueMessagingTemplate = new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQS);
  }

  public void sendMessage(String queueName, String queueMessage) {
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, queueMessage, headers);
  }
```

I can seem to get the message Id of the sent message using `queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, queueMessage, headers);`

I need the messageId to fulfil some business logic.

The second issue is my listener can receive messages however the messageID is null as well;

```
  @Async
  @SqsListener(value = "${notification.sqs-queue-url}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
  public void listen(Acknowledgment acknowledgment, String message, String messageId) {

    //messageId is equal to message here. which is wrong for me
  }
```

The message is always equal to messageId, which is confusing, Any advice on where I maybe going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the listner method signature to

```
 @Async
  @SqsListener(value = "${queue-url}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
  public void listen(Acknowledgment acknowledgment, String message, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    String messageId = (String) headers.get("MessageId");
    acknowledgment.acknowledge().get();
  }
```

Then extracted the messageId from the headers map

Comment: You can also replace `@Headers MessageHeaders headers` with `@Header(name="MessageId") String messageId`, if you want a single header.